# Mongo DB JavaScript using Perl

Tags: mongodb, perl

Can we directly run a Java Script from Perl to get the data from MongoDB ?

Suppose my current JS file is :--

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 194127180 ; 
permissibleCars = 
 ["C:93124617:54413209463","C:93124633:54413165206","C:93124634:54413165224"]

db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
{$match:
  {         "methods.name": "Download",
            "methods.status": "ACTIVE",       
            container: {"$in": permissibleCars},
            entitlementClass : "Download"

    } },
{"$group" : {_id:"$container", count:{$sum:9}}}
],
{ allowDiskUse: true}
);
```

Generally when we run it shell/bash we run it :--

```
mongo hostname:portnumber/db_name - user_name -p password < filename.js > output_file.txt
```

But I am not sure how to run it using perl.

Can someone help me with same ? I read through documentations didnt see anything to JS with perl.

Regards

Comment: Nothing prevents you from shelling out in Perl and running that command. You can also work with https://metacpan.org/pod/JavaScript or another one of that kind to execute your stuff, but I wouldn't recommend it. You can build everything you're doing in that JS file with the Perl implementation of Mongo's API. If the rest of your program is written in Perl, you should probably be doing that, and not some weird kind of hybrid.

Comment: so , same JS would work or do I need to change the JS fornat ?

Comment: Please re-read my comment. The answer to that is _yes, it will work_ and _no, you need to rewrite it_. It depends on how you implement it. The implementation where the answer is _yes_ is error-prone, ugly and probably harder to maintain. But when you rewrite it, you will initially need to learn how to do that first. In the long run, consistency should have higher value though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Perl driver, you'd do that via the [aggregate method](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Collection#aggregate).

It would look something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MongoDB;

my $mc   = MongoDB->connect('mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname');
my $coll = $mc->ns("dbname.Test");

my @permissibleCars =
  ( "C:93124617:54413209463", "C:93124633:54413165206", "C:93124634:54413165224" );

my @pipeline = (
    {
        '$match' => {
            "methods.name"     => "Download",
            "methods.status"   => "ACTIVE",
            "container"        => { '$in' => \@permissibleCars },
            "entitlementClass" => "Download"

        }
    },
    { '$group' => { _id => '$container', count => { '$sum' => 9 } } }
);

my $res = $coll->aggregate( \@pipeline, { allowDiskUse => 1 } );
```

You then get results out of the `$res` iterator with the methods in [MongoDB::QueryResult](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::QueryResult).

Be careful not to use double-quotes with $-prefixed fields you want to send to the database!

Added for verification

```
 use Data::Printer;
 while (my $row = $res->next) {print $row->{'container'}}
```

Comment: I dont see any error coming but the result never gets printed.Updated the result part

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake . I was doing syntax error . Thanks it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Perl's `system()` function to run that command. But that seems like a spectacularly baroque way to do about it when there's [a Perl module for accessing Mongo databases](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB).